# How to export mixed type objects to csv file?

Tags: powershell, object, export-to-csv, mixed

I'm writing a script that returns a list of objects that most of them have different number of properties. When I print it in the console everything is OK, but when I try to export to CSV only those fields that are common in all objects get exported. All others are cropped.

I use the `Add-Member` cmdlet to add more properties but not all of the objects get the same number of properties.

For example I try to export 2 objects where one is like this:

```json
FirstObject:{
  Network0:nic1,
  Network1:nic2,
  Network2:nic3,
  Network3:nic4,
  Name:VirtualMachine1
}

SecondObject:{
  Network0:nic1,
  Network1:nic2,
  Name:VirtualMachine1
}
```

The Network property is added with `Add-Member` cmdlet. The problem I get when exporting to CSV is that `Network2` and `Network3` properties from the first object are cropped and all the columns I get is `Network0`, `Network1`, and `Name`.

What I would like to know is there a way to export all the properties and if one of the objects doesn't have the property, just assign `$null`?

P.S. I have a solution just to add those fields manually with a loop, but I was wondering maybe there is a cleaner solution built in PowerShell which I missed?

**Update:**

I found out that it provides the same columns to the file that are in the first object. All other fields are ignored. So to be more exact I need all columns in all objects. If some objects do not have the field, then it should be printed empty.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you are currently using to do the export.

Comment: I am pipelining all those objects to -->   | export-csv -notypeinformation exported.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few lines of code that add missing properties.

```
#sample setup
$one = [pscustomobject]@{
    Network0='nic1'
    Network1='nic2'
    Network2='nic3'
    Network3='nic4'
    Name='VirtualMachine1'
}


$two = [pscustomobject]@{
    Network0='nic1'
    Network1='nic2'
    Name='VirtualMachine2'
}

$three = [pscustomobject]@{
    Network0='nic1'
    Name='VirtualMachine3'
}

$export = ($one,$two,$three)

#build list of all properties available to $allProps
$export | % -begin { $allProps = @() } -process { $allProps = [linq.enumerable]::union([object[]](($_.psobject.Properties).Name), [object[]]$allProps) }

#convert each object in $export to new custom object having all properties and put to $result
$export | % -begin { $result = @() } -process { $__ = $_; $o = @{ }; $allProps | %{ $o += @{ $_ = $__.$_ } }; $result+=[pscustomobject]$o }

#export $result to csv
$result | Export-Csv $env:TEMP\export.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force

Get-Content $env:TEMP\export.csv

"Network1", "Network3", "Network0", "Name", "Network2"
"nic2", "nic4", "nic1", "VirtualMachine1", "nic3"
"nic2",, "nic1", "VirtualMachine2",
 ,, "nic1", "VirtualMachine3",
>> Script Ended
```

Things to note:

- `[linq.enumerable]::union` is used to easy build list of all available properties across all objects.
- `($_.psobject.Properties).Name` is shortcut to `@($_.psobject.Properties | select -ExpandProperty Name)`, it contains array of property names
- `$__ = $_` is a trick for [nested loop](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4fe18b70-ef6b-4300-89c8-7511aa670114/tricks-for-nested-loops?forum=winserverpowershell)
- `$o += @{ $_ = $__.$_ }` adds key-value pairs to output object; trick here is that even if property `$_='nic4'` does not exists in `$__` export object, powershell does not throw error and returns $null. Note that this will not work when `Set-StrictMode` is set `-Version 2` or later.

Comment: Thank you very much! Probably the hardest one liners I've seen. Thanks for those things to note, really helpful :)